# How to add separate admin menu for custom component

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, menu

By default the custom component can be seen under 'Extensions' menu at admin side.  But how can I create my own menu at the top near to 'Extensions' menu like 'My Component' and show sub menu links under that?

Comment: Are you talking about the same thing Community Builder do? If so, I was initially going to recommend looking through their code, but having looked at it myself I think differently :/

Comment: @Lodder yes, you are correct.  I am expecting a similar module.  I refer the CB module and I see they have lots of code to achieve it.  I thought there could be a simpler way to do and that's the reason of this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can develop an admin side component with the below code snippet.

**mod_custommenu.php**

```
$input   = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$menu    = new JAdminCSSMenu;
$enabled = $input->getBool('hidemainmenu') ? false : true;

// Render the module layout
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_custommenu', $params->get('layout', 'default'));
```

The above code creates a menu object and load the default.php

**default.php**

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$direction = $document->direction == 'rtl' ? 'pull-right' : '';
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_custommenu', $enabled ? 'default_enabled' : 'default_disabled');
$menu->renderMenu('menu', $enabled ? 'nav ' . $direction : 'nav disabled ' . $direction);
```

The above code will determine how the menu to be displayed.  Either enabled or disabled.

**default_disabled.php**

```
$menu->addChild(new JMenuNode(JText::_('Menu'), null, 'disabled'));
```

The above code is just to display the greyed menu in case of disabled.

**default_enabled.php**

```
$menu->addChild(new JMenuNode(JText::_('Menu'), '#'), true);
$menu->addChild(new JMenuNode(JText::_('Menu1'), '', 'class:menu1'), 1);
  $menu->addChild(new JMenuNode(JText::_('Menu2'), '#', 'class:menu2'));
  $menu->getParent();
$menu->getParent();
```

The above code will add the menu and menu items.

Comment: Very complete and well explained, works great, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You will need to override the admin template to do this.

There is a pretty detailed article here that describes how to do this. It was written for Joomla 2.5 but should also work for Joomla 3.0

http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/item/721-Customizing-the-Admin-Menu

Comment: I'm pretty sure there must be an other way: Virtuemart 3 appears in the top menu after install.

Comment: They can do that by simply adding a template override during installation

Answer (score -1):

I was doing it myself but now I use https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/admin-menu-manager